# Error code : 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: java, mysql, sql, constraints

I am trying to create a database but every time I try to do so I get the error message:

```
1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint.
```

I've been searching for the solution all morning but can't find anything that helps my problem, here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Lid (
        lid_id          INT(2)      NOT NULL,
        naam            VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
        email           VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
        tel_nummer      VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
        score           INT(2)      NOT NULL,
        expertise       VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
        team_id         INT(2)      NOT NULL,
primary key (lid_id),
foreign key (team_id) references Team(team_id));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Team (
        team_id     INT(2)          NOT NULL,
        naam        VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
        score       INT(2)          NOT NULL,
        captain     INT(2)          NOT NULL,
        expertise   VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
primary key (team_id),
foreign key (captain) references Lid(lid_id));
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a `FOREIGN KEY` you need both source and target fields and tables created.

Example: In order to create a foreign key from field `b_id` in table `A` to field `id` in table `B` You first need to create tables A and B with its fields, in that case you can define B first and then A with its foreign key.

In your case: you need to create the foreign keys after table definitions, using `ALTER TABLE` because both tables references to each other.

So your code should be like this:

```
/* DEFINE TABLES */

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Lid (
        lid_id          INT(2)      NOT NULL,
        naam            VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
        email           VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
        tel_nummer      VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
        score           INT(2)      NOT NULL,
        expertise       VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
        team_id         INT(2)      NOT NULL,
primary key (lid_id));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Team (
        team_id     INT(2)          NOT NULL,
        naam        VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
        score       INT(2)          NOT NULL,
        captain     INT(2)          NOT NULL,
        expertise   VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
primary key (team_id));

/* CREATE FOREIGN KEYS */
ALTER TABLE Lid  ADD FOREIGN KEY (team_id)  REFERENCES Team(team_id);
ALTER TABLE Team ADD FOREIGN KEY (captain)  REFERENCES Lid(lid_id);
```

You can see more explanation and examples in [SQL FOREIGN KEY Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the foreign key before creating the referenced table.
You better create both tables, and then use `ALTER TABLE` statements to add the foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 0):

First create the team table and then create the lid one. What mysql is basically telling you is that it doesn't know the team_id field you are referencing as a foreign key constraint.

Comment: but team also has a lid foreign key

Answer (score 0):

**STEP-1**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Lid (
    lid_id          INT(2)      NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    naam            VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    email           VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    tel_nummer      VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    score           INT(2)      NOT NULL,
    expertise       VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    team_id         INT(2)      NOT NULL
)
```

**STEP-2**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Team (
    team_id     INT(2)          NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    naam        VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    score       INT(2)          NOT NULL,
    captain     INT(2)          NOT NULL,
    expertise   VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
)
```

**STEP-3**

```
ALTER TABLE lid ADD FOREIGN KEY ( team_id ) REFERENCES team( team_id )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for editing my code now its showing in a simple way.

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress checking of validity of foreign keys temporarily in a session (both for purposes of defining tables and inserting data) with:

```
set foreign_key_checks=0;
```

then restore it with:

```
set foreign_key_checks=1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Lid (
        lid_id          INT(2)      NOT NULL,
        naam            VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
        email           VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
        tel_nummer      VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
        score           INT(2)      NOT NULL,
        expertise       VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
        team_id         INT(2)      NOT NULL,
primary key (lid_id));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Team (
        team_id     INT(2)          NOT NULL,
        naam        VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
        score       INT(2)          NOT NULL,
        captain     INT(2)          NOT NULL,
        expertise   VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
primary key (team_id),
foreign key (captain) references Lid(lid_id));

ALTER TABLE Lid ADD foreign key (team_id) references Team(team_id);
```